# TYPO3: Page type external url, open external links in new window for default

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm looking for a solution to open external menu links in a new window for default. (without writing _blank in the target field)
But without changing the url, the url should be anymore e.g. ..../test.html not ...www.external-url.co.....

I already tried

in typoscript

```
config.extTarget = _blank
```

in constants

```
styles.content.links.extTarget = _blank
```

But with no success. Thank you for help.

Comment: Do you need to open only the external links in typoscript menu in new window?

Comment: Mh no but I think I need another solution, the problem is if I log in into my restricted area on the website and then using the back button of the browser after clicking on a menu item, the browser shows me an error with "document dead"

Comment: please create a new post for the "document dead" issue and provide more details related to the issues mentioned in this post.
Is realurl enabled? Also do you need only the external links in menu created using typoscript to be opened in a new window?

Answer (score 6):

Just edit the sites properties of your external link: Go to the Behaviour-Tab and insert *_blank* in field **Link Target**. Your external link should now open in a new window/tab.

Comment: It's specifically said "without writing _blank in the target field"

Answer (score 3):

If you need to open the external urls in menu in new window, then please check and try the below typoscript:

```
lib.mainmenu = HMENU
lib.mainmenu {
  special = directory
  special.value = 1
  1=TMENU
  1.wrap=<ul>|</ul>
  1.NO {
    # do not create a link here else there are double <a> tags
    doNotLinkIt = 1
    wrapItemAndSub=<li>|</li>
    stdWrap.cObject = CASE
    stdWrap.cObject {
      key.field = doktype
      default = TEXT
      default {
        field = title
        typolink.parameter.field = uid
        stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
      }

      # 3 = external url
      3 = TEXT
      3 {
        field = title
        typolink.parameter.field = url
        typolink.extTarget = _blank
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this helped me out because it was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!!! But anyway it doesn't answer the question correctly  "the url should be anymore e.g. ..../test.html not ...www.external-url.co....."

Answer (score 3):

Sankar version can be simplied and if "target" is set menu item will take the field value.

```
lib.mainmenu = HMENU
lib.mainmenu{
    entryLevel = 0
    1 = TMENU
    1{
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        NO = 1 
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        NO.ATagParams{
            override = target="_blank"
            override.if{
                isFalse.field = target
                equals = 3
                value.field = doktype
            }
        }
        ACT < .NO
        ACT.ATagParams.noTrimWrap = |class="active" ||
    }
}
```

Comment: while this actually answering the question it does not the same as Sankars code for Sankars version replaces the href with the external URL while this one still points to the internal page (which makes a redirect afterwards)

Answer (score 1):

Just use jQuery and don't worry about the CMS

```
$("a[href^='http:']:not([href*='" + window.location.host + "'])").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Comment: There are several reasons for my answer: 1. It's not easy to achieve in TYPO3. 2. The discussion about _blank validity and W3C compliance is unsolved and there are CMSes that don't support it like the excellent www.grabaperch.com - but 3. Normal Users still require the new window very much. - so I myself go for the jQuery way; also setting PDF links to _blank etc. this way

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me in this way:

I went to **Template** module then to the main page of the site (home page)

Then i selected the "typoscript object browser" and searched "extTarget" in the "costants" and clicked on the result and there it was possible to change the target.

I saved and it worked well!

Comment: Explain your answer; code without explanation isn't very useful.